# 406 (Not Acceptable) error on rails and jquery mobile autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-mobile

I keep getting this 406 (Not Acceptable) error when i type in an autocomplete field.

I am using jquery mobile and jquery ui autocomplete and rails

here is my jquery

```
$("#request_artist").focus(function(){ 
    $("#request_artist").autocomplete({ 
        source: function(req, add){ 
            $.getJSON(artistRequestUrl, req, function(data) { 
                var suggestions = data.suggestions; 
                add(suggestions);    
            });   
        },
        change: function() {
            $("#request_song").attr("disabled", false); 
            $("#request_submit").attr("disabled", false); 
            $("#request_like_reason").attr("disabled", false); 
            $('.disable_color').css("color", "black");   
        },    
    });
});
```

here is my html

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="search">Artist</label>
    <input type="search" name="password" id="request_artist" value="" />
</div>
```

here is my rails action

```
def ajax_artist
  bands = Band.all
  artists = bands.map(&:name).uniq.sort
  filter_input(artists, params[:term])
  Rails.logger.info @all_instances_hash.inspect
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @all_instances_hash}
  end
end
```

if i look at the logger in the console i get this for @all_instances_hash if i enter the letter c

```
 {:query=>"c", :suggestions=>["Casting Crowns", "John Mark McMillan"]}
```

But the autocomplete is not working...any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that Rails thinks you're asking for HTML back. Your `ajax_artist` can only ever respond (sensibly) with JSON so try ignoring the format completely:

```
def ajax_artist
  bands = Band.all
  artists = bands.map(&:name).uniq.sort
  filter_input(artists, params[:term])
  Rails.logger.info @all_instances_hash.inspect
  render :json => @all_instances_hash
end
```